# Is there a way to send (python) code to a server to compile and run but display the results on the computer that sent them?

Tags: python, remote-access

I just bought a server and was wondering if there was a way to run the code remotely but store/display the results locally. For example, I write some code to display a graph, the positions on the graph are computed by the (remote) server, but the graph is displayed on the (local) tablet.

I would like to do this because the tablet I carry around with me on a day-to-day basis is very slow for computational physics simulations. I understand that I can setup some kind of communications protocol that allows the server to compute things and then sends the computations to my tablet for a script on my tablet to handle the data. However, I would like to avoid writing a possibly new set of communications scripts (to handle different formats of data) every single time I run a new simulation.

Answer (score -1):

This is a complete "[The Russians used a pencil](http://therussiansusedapencil.com/post/175863624/the-pencil)" solution, but have you considered running a VNC server on the machine that is doing the computations?

You could install a VNC client onto your tablet/phone/PC and view it that way, there are tons of them available. No need to go about creating anything from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

With ssh, you can do this with a python script or a shell script.

`ssh machine_name "python" < ~/script/path/script.py`

As the OP indicated in the comments that he wants to interact with the script on the remote machine, I have made some change here.

1. Copy the python or shell script to the remote machine. This can be done in several ways. For example with `scp`. But also, with `ssh`, like here:

`ssh machine_name bash -c "cat > /tmp/script.py" < ~/script/path/script.py`

2. Interact with the script on the remote machine

`ssh machine_name python -u /tmp/script.py`

You should be able to interact with your script running in the remote machine now!

Notice the use of `-u` to set stdin/stdout of python in unbuffered mode. This is needed to be able to interact with the script.

> ```
>    -u     Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered.  On systems where it  matters,  also  put  stdin,
>           stdout  and stderr in binary mode.  Note that there is internal buffering in xreadlines(), readlines() and
>           file-object iterators ("for line in sys.stdin") which is not influenced by this option.   To  work  around
>           this, you will want to use "sys.stdin.readline()" inside a "while 1:" loop.
> ```

Here is an example.
The code, which was copied to the server:

```
#!/usr//bin/env python3

while True:
    value = input("Please enter the value: ")
    if value != "bye":
        print("Input received from the user is: ", value)
    else:
        print("Good bye!!")
        break
```

Interactive session:

```
$ ssh  machine_name python -u python/pyecho.py
Please enter the value: 123
Input received from the user is:  123
Please enter the value: bye 
Good bye!!
```

REF:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87405/how-can-i-execute-local-script-on-remote-machine-and-include-arguments
- Feedback in the comments below.

Comment: This works as long as `script.py` itself doesn't try to read from standard input.

Comment: @chepner The solution is working fine since the edit of 2020. It can read and write from the standard input without an issue.

Comment: Someone else cast the downvote, not me. (As an aside, `scp ~/script/path/script.py desktop:/tmp/script.py` is a lot simpler.) The update still assumes that the script will read from standard input rather than directly from the keyboard (but it's an improvement).

Comment: No, the script works fine with the keyboard.

Comment: That depends on the script, not your method for connecting standard input. `cat - | ssh ...` is just a convoluted way of writing `ssh ...` anyway. `cat` reads from local standard input without any arguments (`-` is useful for concatenating standard output with *other* files), and `ssh` read from local standard output without the pipe.

Comment: You are right! Thanks for the info. I'll update the answer.